# knitr printing list of data.frames with each table on new page

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyverse, knitr, purrr

I want to print `list` of `data.frames` with each table on new page. The `for-loop` works fine but requires long code. Tried with `map` function but could not get the required output. Not able to use `\newpage` command with `map` function. It also gives some extra output like `[[1]] NULL [[2]] NULL`. Any hint, please.

```
mt1 <-
  matrix(
    data = runif(n = 200, min = 101, max = 999)
  , nrow = 20
  , ncol = 10
  , byrow = TRUE
  , dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:20], paste0("V", 1:10))
  )

df1 <- data.frame(Name = row.names(mt1), mt1) 

dfs <- 
  unname(
    split.default(
    df1[, -1], as.integer(gl(ncol(df1)-1,  5, ncol(df1) - 1))
    )
    )


library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)


for(i in 1:length(dfs)){
  print(
    kable(
      cbind(df1[1], dfs[i])
      , format = 'latex'
      , row.names = FALSE
    ) %>% 
      row_spec(row = c(0), bold = TRUE, italic = TRUE, align = "l")
    )
  if(i < length(dfs)) {
  cat("\n\n\\newpage\n")
    }
  }

map(
  dfs
  , function(x) 
    print(
      kable(
       cbind(df1[1], x)
      , format = 'latex'
      , row.names = FALSE
    ) %>% 
    row_spec(row = c(0), bold = TRUE, italic = TRUE, align = "l")
    #cat("\n\n\\newpage\n")
    )
  #if(i < length(x))
    #cat("\n\n\\newpage\n")
  )
```

Comment: when you say "new page," what kind of document are you creating? Are you knitting a .Rmd to html?

Comment: It is `.Rnw` document.

Comment: I have difficulties understanding how to code with `for` is "longer" or otherwise inferior to the `map` version (in this case). Are you just trying to avoid imperative programming in favor of a functional approach ... for the sake of [something]?

Comment: I have the same difficulty as @CL.. The `for` loop seems to be totally legitimate here. I don't really see the point of having to use `purrr::map()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `purrr::imap` to get the index in the `.y` variable:

````
``` r
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

mt1 <-
  matrix(
    data = runif(n = 200, min = 101, max = 999)
    ,
    nrow = 20
    ,
    ncol = 10
    ,
    byrow = TRUE
    ,
    dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:20], paste0("V", 1:10))
  )

df1 <- data.frame(Name = row.names(mt1), mt1)

dfs <-
  unname(split.default(df1[,-1], as.integer(gl(
    ncol(df1) - 1,  5, ncol(df1) - 1
  ))))

f <- function() {
  for (i in 1:length(dfs)) {
    print(
      kable(
        cbind(df1[1], dfs[i])
        ,
        format = 'latex'
        ,
        row.names = FALSE
      ) %>%
        row_spec(
          row = c(0),
          bold = TRUE,
          italic = TRUE,
          align = "l"
        )
    )
    if (i < length(dfs)) {
      cat("\n\n\\newpage\n")
    }
  }
}

f_map <- function() {
  invisible(dfs %>% purrr::imap(~ {
    print(
      kable(cbind(df1[1], .x)
            , format = 'latex'
            , row.names = FALSE) %>%
        row_spec(
          row = c(0),
          bold = TRUE,
          italic = TRUE,
          align = "l"
        )
      #cat("\n\n\\newpage\n")
    )
    if (.y < length(dfs))
      cat("\n\n\\newpage\n")
  }))
}

identical(capture.output(f()), capture.output(f_map()))
#> [1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark( f = {res <- capture.output(f())}, f_map = {res <- capture.output(f_map())})
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#>      f 7.908510 8.431997 9.662659 9.012099 10.10318 15.42358   100   a
#>  f_map 7.983586 8.462561 9.797256 9.150356 10.71692 16.20676   100   a
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
````

As stated by @CL, this is not faster nor shorter than a simple loop.